# SQL query for Projects Not Listed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an MSSQL database that users log time spent working on certain projects.  I have two tables, that are made up of these fields

```
Project - <ID>,<DESCRIPTION>
ProjectTime - <ID>,<PROJECTID>,<DATE>
```

These tables have been greatly simplified, but I am trying to figure out how to get a list of projects, just the description field, that have no time logged against them in the past few weeks.  I have been trying to use queries like this

```
WHERE NOT DATE > '2017-04-21'
```

but I am not getting anywhere.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXISTS`, or in this case, `NOT EXISTS`

```
select P1.*
from Project P1
where not exists 
(select 1
 from ProjectTime PT
 where PT.Date > '2017-04-21'
 and PT.ProjectID = P1.ID
)
```

Comment: Thanks JohnHC.  Being an SQL query novice, it took me a bit to decode the query, but I got it.  It works great.